# Best practice generating object for response

Tags: java, json

I have rest server with spring.
There is a lot of requests where one of the params is `fields` fields is the set of fields that server should return in response. like: `/?fields=[id,name]` and server should return JSON object with both fields
I would like to know what is the best practice for generating such response.
We do it like this:

```
private Map<String, Object> processBook(BookEntity book, Set<String> fields, String locale){
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//..
        if(fields.contains(ID)){
            map.put(ID, book.getId());
        }
        if(fields.contains(ISBN)){
            map.put(ISBN, book.getIsbn());
        }
        if(fields.contains(DESCRIPTION)){
            if(locale.equals(UserLocale.UK))        map.put(DESCRIPTION, book.getDescriptionUa());
            else if(locale.equals(UserLocale.RU))   map.put(DESCRIPTION, book.getDescriptionRu());
            else                                    map.put(DESCRIPTION, book.getDescriptionEn());
        }
//..
        return map;
    }
```

Maybe there is much better alternative?

Comment: Using a library like GSON or Jackson are good alternatives to parsing json or converting them to objects. If you want to stick with a Hashmap, I don't see anything wrong here

Comment: You could use reflection but to be honest, I think this approach is fine

Comment: I do not know if it is the best practice, but the method could return a specific object (like book, with fields as id,isbn, and so on) instead a hashmap using [Apache CXF] (https://cxf.apache.org/), is a less generic approach altough it is more abstract, intuitive and easily to maintain (and debug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your case you obtain all data from DB - fully filled **BookEntity** object, and then show only requested fields.

In my opinion it'd be "much better alternative" to delegate field list to appropriate downstream integration call and get **BookEntity** object only with necessary fields. Then mentioned above method will reduce to just one line, your DB responses will be more lightweight, so it will bring simplicity and optimization gain to your system.

Any adequate DB provides such functionality: SQL or NoSQL, etc.

P.S. Plus standard approach of Object to JSON mapping such as Jackson or GSON at top level.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a Map, you could have and object with the attributes you need and set them, instead of adding to map.
Then you can use Google's Gson to transform your object into a Json object.
Take a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) quick tutorial.

Comment: emm. i need to generate different responses for different requests.

../?fields=[id,isbn] and ../?fields=[id,name] - are different requests. Will Gson solve this? could i use it to generate such responses?

Comment: Gson does not serialize a field if its value is `null`. So you could set non-required fields on BookEntity to `null` and then use Gson to serialize the instance. Personally, I think the HashMap approach is simpler.

Comment: As @W.K.S said, null values are not serialized. So you could have a DTO with all values that might arrive, and set those that your are getting in the request. This I mentioned is just an alternative. Don't think there is a "BEST PRACTICE", but different alternatives that can be easier to read into.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have an asMap function.

```
 Map<String, Object> map = book.asMap();
 map.keySet().retainAll(fields);
```